# Android - Google map marker with animationDrawable

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Im building an app using c# and Xamarin and google maps.

I've looked everywhere and I couldnt find any explantion on how I should do it and if its possible.

I have this xml: (map_icon.xml):

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="true">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/MapUserIcon01" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/MapUserIcon02" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/MapUserIcon03" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/MapUserIcon04" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/MapUserIcon05" android:duration="100" />  
</animation-list>
```

I want to use it as my marker icon:

```
var myMarker = new MarkerOptions();
myMarker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.map_icon));
myMarker.SetPosition(new LatLng(currentLocation.Latitude, currentLocation.Longitude));
driver = Gmap.AddMarker(myMarker);
```

But the problem is that Icon dosent have backgorund property, so I cant start the animation!

**EDIT:**
This is the animation that I want to do:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nMqS.gif

What is the propper way to do it?

Both c# and Java solution are welcome!

Thnx!

Comment: Are you trying to animate the marker? how the animation should be?

Comment: @Dinash yes I'm trying to animate the marker, I added an image of the animation.

Comment: Not able to see the image that you added

Comment: @Dinash https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nMqS.gif